# CSS sidebar dropping on page for no reason?

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I have my entire site working and laying out correctly and for the life of me I can't figure out why on one particular page the right sidebar/column is dropping below the center content? I tried to compare both pages in seperate browsers using firebug and they look the same except for the content?  What gives?

[Layout works great here](http://tinyurl.com/7pdh9tu)

[Dropping sidebar here](http://tinyurl.com/6w6zorh)

Comment: When floated elements 'drop', that means there isn't enough space for them to appear in the proper place. Either the element is too wide, or the other elements it'd be sharing the line with are too wide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They aren't the same.

In [the second example](http://www.progresstechnologies.com/swflrealtors/events-2/category/ce-classes/), the element #primary (the right sidebar) is a child element of #container, which it isn't in the first example. If I should guess, I would suggest that there is an unclosed `div` somwhere…

Comment: This is the same thing I saw.

Comment: Yes!  their pre-formatted code was missing the closing div tag...thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Re-aranged the order on the HTML side, to have the div order in the "main" go - Order was different in the second link, causing the layout to break:

```
<div id="main>
   <p style.....
   <div id="third....
   <div id="container....
   <div id="primary....
   <div id="secondary....
</div>
```

I've removed the divs primary and secondary from the mid container, I don't see why they were in there.

Also I've removed the property clear:right from the container div, worked for me.